lambda transaccional en aws dynamodb para generar un contador de registros nuevos de una tabla en otra tabla
en dynamodb tengo una tabla "votos" que registra un email único, y solo una opción (de 10 posibles), en el hipotético caso de que se realicen mas de 1000 votos por segundo, podria ejecutar una lambda que se accione cada 25 registros nuevos y acumule la cantidad de votos (opción) recibidos en otra tabla "eleccion"  que contiene con 10 elementos (las opciones) y un atributo valor que seria el acumulador?
La duda es como hago un control de concurrencia de escritura para que no se pierdan votos.
La escritura transaccional evitaría esto para esta cantidad de votos por segundo?
Las tablas serian on-demand.
Sdos y gracias!

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
